# Open automatically an input file dialog when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html

In one of some web personal project, I want to automatically ask to the user to upload a file when the page is loaded. (the user don't need to click anywhere, the dialog appears automatically)

(then after, I build some parts of the page depending of the content of the file)

I tried with this very simple code : ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ac9fL837/))

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type','file'); // generate a '<input type="file">' tag
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  input.click(); // nothing happen here
  //document.body.removeChild(input);
});
```

But nothing happen and I don't get any error...
Where is my mystake ? I don't understand

Comment: In Chrome, with your fiddle I get a warning shown saying, _“File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation.”_ - which means what you want is explicitly _not_ possible.

Comment: haaaa, I tested with firefox and see nothing

Comment: For security reasons you cannot call `click` without an input from the user, in fact if you change `DOMContentLoaded` to a user generated event, such as `click` for example, your script will work (several times).